# WordPress/WooCommce - Send Payment From Site's PayPal Account To Another PayPal Account

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

**Scenario:**
 I am working on a crowdfunding site. Here are the steps I am following.

1. Campaign creator creates a campaign on the site.
2. The contributor sees the campaign and contribute to it using PayPal.
3. The site will hold the funds raised to the campaign and would release when the campaign reaches its goal. i.e All the funds would go to site's PayPal account till the campaign reaches its goal.
4. When the campaign reaches its goal, the site will transfer the funds from site's PayPal account to the campaign creator's PayPal account.

**Question:** I am on the fourth step. The site receives all the funds of a campaign. I need to hook some function along with the campaign completion function that'd send the funds from site's paypal account to campaign creators PayPal account.
I need your suggestions how can I do that? Any functions that can do this part?

**The payment handling is being done with woocommerce if that helps.**

Comment: did you find any solution for point 4..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayPal isn't going to allow you to use your account as a escrow like you are explaining.  You may get away with it for a little while, but eventually they'll see what's going on and they'll shut it down.  Then you could be in bad shape if you had a bunch of stuff going on at the time.

What you're going to need to do is work with [Preapprovals](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/).  Specifically, the [Preapproval API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/).

Contributors won't be paying any money up front, but instead they'll be setting up a preapproval profile with your application so that you can trigger a payment on their behalf when/if you need to.

When a goal is reached and payments need to be triggered your app would process all of those payments using the preapproval keys for each contributor via the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).

Not only is this the way PayPal is going to require you handle it, but it will also avoid double fees if you're paying a fee when you receive the payment and then the person you send the money to later would also be paying a fee.

There aren't any plugins readily available for WordPress / WooCommerce that are going to get that done for you out of the box, but if you're familiar with building your own plugins you can use this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) to make those API calls very quick and easy for you.

Comment: Thank you for the best explanation. While I was surfing, I got the MassPay API. I even got a code working that sends the payment. But as you have pointed it, would it still be bad if I do with MassPay? I am doing with some API credentials and stuff like that.

Comment: One more thing. I was reading the documentations all the day long and have few questions now. The most important is the pre-approval method does not guarantee the availability of funds throughout the campaign duration. So if some of the contributors won't have sufficient funds in their accounts when the campaign reaches its goal, then the creator won't get the required funds. No Guarantee.

Comment: How it would be possible to make a platform that allows flexible funding i.e. whether the campaign reaches its goal or not, the creator would get the available funds when the campaign expires. Like I have created a campaign and want to receive $100USD in 3 days. After three days, I get $90USD in contributions. The method you have listed would only release the funds if there are $100USD contributions. So how the platform would make sure to send me those $90USD as a flexible funding type?

Comment: MassPay needs to be specifically approved on your account in order to use it, and they would see what you're doing right away.  It would probably just get declined.  You are correct, Preapprovals do not guarantee the funds will be available.  It only allows you to attempt a payment on their behalf without further approval, but it could simply fail.   As for how the solution works with flexible funding, that's completely up to you and your app development.  You can trigger payments whenver/however you want to.

Comment: So any way I can guarantee the payments? The campaigns would last several months. That's why I was trying to be an escrow. But as you have pointed out, that won't be going to last any much longer. Any solution to make guaranteed payments?